# pass value from html form to javascript function with the use of radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have problem in passing value from the database in php and html to javascript function.

Here is the situation. A list of records will display with corresponding radio button. When the radio button is clicked, the record selected from the list will appear on a textbox and depending on the selected record, records will be retrieved from the database and display them to textboxes. I did it but I cannot retrieve records in the database and display them to textboxes. Please help me.

Here are my codes:

This is the code in HTML and PHP:

```
EMAIL:<input type="text" name="emp_email" id="emp_email">
Employee ID:<input type="text" name="asEmpId" id="txtAsEmpId">
Role:
<select name="Role" id="cbRole">
<option value="employee">Attendee</option>
<option value="organizer">Event Organizer</option>
</select>

<form id='maillist' name='maillist'>
<?php
$qry="select emp_id,emp_code, req_role, emp_email
        from tbl_request_access
        where acs_transfer='PE'";   

$res=insert_select_update($qry);
$numrow=checknumrow($qry);
if($numrow>0)
{
?><form><?php
        print "<table class=\"emaillist\" >
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody> ";
        while($data=mysql_fetch_row($res))      
        {
            print "<tr class=\"odd\">

                    <td><input type='radio'  name='emailid[]' id='check'        value='$data[3]' onclick='appendtomail2(\"maillist\");'></td>
                    <td>$data[3]</td>   

                </tr>";
                ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" value='<?php echo $data[0]?>'>
                <input type="hidden" name="role" id="role" value='<?php echo $data[2]?>'>
                <?php
        }
        print "</tbody>
        </table>";
        ?></form><?php
    }
    </form>
```

Here are my codes in external Javascript:

```
function appendtomail2(delform)
{
    document.getElementById('emp_email').value='';
    var val='';
    var valcode='';
    var aa= document.getElementById(delform);
    for (var i =2; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
    {
        if(aa.elements[i].checked)
        {
            var valsplit=aa.elements[i].value.substring(parseInt(aa.elements[i].value.search(';')));
            var val=val+valsplit;
        }
        else
        {
            var val=val;
            var valcode=valcode;
        }
    }
    if(val.length>2)
    {
        document.getElementById('emp_email').value=valsplit;
        document.getElementById('txtAsEmpId').value='';  //for the text box
        document.getElementById('cbRole').value='';      //for the text box
        document.getElementById("btnAssignRole").disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('emp_email').value='';
        document.getElementById('txtAsEmpId').value='';
        document.getElementById('cbRole').value=''; 
        document.getElementById("btnAssignRole").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the query I would use to retrieve the record from database:
    $qry="select emp_id, req_role, emp_email
            from tbl_request_access
            where acs_transfer='PE' and emp_email='$data[3]'";

```
        //$data[3] is the selected value
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side and JavaScript is Client side this is the problem. What you really want is a PHP variable to Javascript.

Options...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var php_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
</script>
```

You can also load it by using JavaScript AJAX call. Have PHP return some json data such as

```
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Have this code fired when a radio button with is clicked ...

```
$("input[name=someRadioGroup]:radio").change(function () {});
```

I use name in my example because usually you have multiple radio buttons with one name